# Memory leak in jboss service due to DefaultListableBeanFactory objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector

In my jboss service, I get memory leak. I checked the heap dump, I saw the major portion of heap is occupied by DefaultListableBeanFactory and ConcurrentHashMap.

I came across this issue reported already, 
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9842

My issue is also the same but I use spring(spring-beans) version 3.1.1.RELEASE. Can somebody help if this is actually a problem with spring or is it a problem with my code? Also if it is a problem with the spring, what is the solution?

Thanks

Comment: Well, hard to confirm, deny or proof this bug, even the reported one in jira. Can you create a test-case for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the cause of the problem. The issue was that, in the code [ClassPathXmlApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html) object is instantiated for each request.

I changed the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext object to static and now I no longer face this problem. Thanks for the support.

The comment in the link explained the problem,
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7502?focusedCommentId=57240&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-57240

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I just got the same problem and solved it with a static variable.